Component installation problem with "Indy 10 for Delphi 6" installer
We use Delphi 6 and the IndyRegister.exe program for "Indy 10 for Delphi 6". After the last Windows system update, when reinstalling Delphi 6 on a new computer, we can no longer install Indy with IndyRegister.exe, it gives us this error message:

This version of Delphi is not installed

What happened that the installed Delphi 6 version is not recognized and it is not possible to install Indy 10 components for Delphi?
We are trying these steps:

and we get this result:


AToZed's installer is an unofficial 3rd party installer, it is not supported by Indy. You need to contact AToZed directly for support. AFAIK, that installer has not been updated in a very long time. Indy does not have an official installer.  You can simply compile and install the component packages manually, see https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy for instructions

Delphi 6 in 2024, holy cow. You really need to move on.

@IanKemp the company I spent most of my professional career with used C++Builder 6 for almost 20 years, it was our primary money-maker. If we hadn't been bought out a few years ago, I'm sure we would still be using it today. Old IDEs can still produce viable projects for modern Windows versions, especially if you don't need the fancy (cough cough buggy) features of newer IDEs.
